# When should a function *not* be defined with "abort"

Tags: functions, error

If you define a function with the `abort` argument, your function will abort as soon as an error is detected. Is there any case where this is *not* what you'd want?

Even if your function needs to perform some final cleanup, I'd expect using `finally` in combination with `abort` would be the best practice, e.g.

```
function! Foo() abort
  call s:make_mess()
  try
    call s:might_fail()
  finally
    call s:cleanup()
  endtry
endfunction
```

Is there any case where you'd actually want *non*-abort behavior?

Comment: Expected failure ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discl.: It's just guessing on my part.

`abort` didn't exist when `function` was introduced. I guess that in order to not break existing code it was decided to not change the current behaviour and to provide another behaviour only when functions are explicitly annotated.

Now, where should we not use it? I see no good reason. Even if a non annotated function continues after an error, we do observe many annoying error messages about unbalanced control statements (`if`, `while`...).

When I execute code that can fail, I'd rather be explicit with `silent!`, `try...catch` or any other specific approach. I do have many non-`abort`-annotated functions, it's just a sign they are very old and that I haven't upgraded them yet.